# Dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 on ssd+hdd not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, uefi

I just bought my laptop with windows 10 on it, and two disk an SSD and HDD. Windows 10 is already installed on SSD. I partitioned HDD into 3 partitions and one of the partitions I installed ubuntu from USB and the "something else" option instead of install alongside windows. The partion with ubuntu is using ext4 file system.

The problem is that when I restart the computer I don't see the option to select ubuntu. Windows 10 is booting automatically.

So far this is [the best answer I got](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735852/windows-10-on-ssd-and-ubuntu-on-hdd) but the problem is that I can only desable secure mode if I switch the boot mode from UEFI to LEGACY mode. However when I switch to legacy mode windows boot manager is disable, and when I boot, I get

> No boot device found error.

How do I see the OS selection after booting? because basically ubuntu is surelly installed on the partition I want it to but I don't get why there is option to select the operating system.

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI or BIOS/Legacy boot mode. With Secure boot off, either mode should be available. But you want UEFI. In UEFI mode grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition in sda. But better to have an ESP on every drive with an install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/591193/install-ubuntu-alongside-win-8-1-on-separate-physical-drives-and-dual-boot &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Please boot the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode and run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot order, I think "Windows boot loader" (or something alike) is on top so grub wont load.

Set grub as the first boot option and you will boot into grub, where you will have the option to choose either windows or Ubuntu.

If grub isnt in the list you probably have to add it manually via one of the options in your BIOS or by disabling secure boot and install ubuntu again.